# Is it possible to open submenu in jQuery mmenu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mmenu

```
<nav id="menu2">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#/">Home</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#/">h1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/">h2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/">h3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/">h4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/">h5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#/">History</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/">The team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/">Our address</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I want show 'home' submneu when I click a link like this:

```
<a id="home">open home menu</a>
```

also I could navigate parents and it childs..

Is it possible?

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/yhta5ux7/8/
when I click on menu1, it opens root menus. I want **open home** menu by default. 
(I want open root menu by 'mwnu1' link and **home** menu by 'open home' link. I hope you got my mean.

Comment: Can you provide some more info? A fiddle and a moe detailed description?

Comment: It is entirely possible, but you'll need to provide more info to get concrete advice

Comment: this is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yhta5ux7/8/

Answer (score 1):

On the official mmenu page:

> Open submenus Click the entire menu item to open a submenu.
>
> The plugin assumes every A element in the menu should be clickable and
>   therefor adds the link to open a submenu next to them. If you replace
>   the A with a SPAN, the entire menu item becomes clickable:

```
<nav id="my-menu">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
      <li><span>About us</span>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="/about/history">History</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about/team">The team</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about/address">Our address</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

[mmenu tips and tricks](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/support/tips-and-tricks.html)

Comment: thanks for the answer. please check my updated question. It is not my answer,